# SonarQube how to creat custom rule for xml with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube

- SonaQube:6.4
- sonar-scanner:3.0.3
- project name:testxml

I have fllow the guide https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+XPath create a xpath rule , and active it in `saas xml rules`.

the xpath rule 7 fileds like this:

- name -> myXmlRule
- keyword -> myXmlRule
- description -> test
- severity  -> major
- statues -> ready
- filePattern ->
- schemas -> //ATTRIBUTE[@tokenValue='lang']

the schemas `//ATTRIBUTE[@tokenValue='lang']` success in `xmlToolKit`,that means schemas is correct.
[image]

the new rule named `myXmlRule`, has actived in Qualiy Profile `saas xml rules`

[image]
[image]

My goal is find `title` node  with `lang` attribute, then raise it.
How to write rule?

test.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>
<book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book>
    <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

In my project `testxml` only `test.xml` and `sonar-project.properties`

in project folder run `sonar-scanner`, it take error message

```
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
16:41:11.456 WARN: Could not find schema //ATTRIBUTE[@tokenValue='lang']
16:41:11.456 WARN: Cannot validate file /Users/zt/Desktop/testXml/test.xml
16:41:11.457 WARN: Cause: org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks.XmlSchemaCheck$SchemaNotFoundException: Could not load schema "//ATTRIBUTE[@tokenValue='lang']"
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct rule ? The _schema_ parameter would indicate that you're using rule rule '_XML files should be valid_' , whereas the rule for XPath checks is '_Track breaches of an XPath rule_' ( _xml:XPathCheck_ ).

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam thanks, it works. Create new rule must check `Track breaches of an XPath rule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule to create XPath checks is '*Track breaches of an XPath rule*' (*xml:XPathCheck*) , not '*XML files should be valid*' (the one shown in your screenshot).