# How to create custom rules for XML in SonarQube?

Tags: xml, sonarqube

I need to write custom rules for XMl in Sonarqube. I tried some templates here. https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples. But its not working for XML. Anyone is having template for sonar XML plugins?

Comment: Hope this might help https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/#header-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204519/sonarqube-how-to-creat-custom-rule-for-xml-with-xpath

Answer (score 0):

finally I was able to update sonar xml plugin and add my logic there.
I have added/modified 4 files to implement one custom rule.

1. src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/xml/checks/SynapsCheck.java
   Added new file which includes validation logic.
2. src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/xml/checks/CheckList.java
   Class name should be added to this check list
3. src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/xml/rules/xml/SynapsCheck.html
   HTML file which contains web content in sonar web page
4. src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/xml/rules/xml/SynapsCheck.json
   Json file which contains rule metadata

You can find complete solution [here](https://github.com/hasithahpw/sonar-xml)

**Note** : This is replacing existing sonar xml plugin hence please be careful while modifying files

Comment: I get this error in the console when I try to start SonarQube

**ERROR app[][startup] Startup failed: Plugins can't be loaded. See web logs for more information**

when I check my web.log file I found this

**ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.PlatformImpl] Web server startup failed: Found a plugin 'SonarXML' in the directory 'extensions\plugins' with the same key [xml] as a built-in feature 'XML Code Quality and Security'. Please remove 'extensions\plugins\original-sonar-xml-plugin-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'.**

Did you face the same problem before @Hasitha

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube v8.5+ does not support custom xml plugin as it has been made a part of the sonarqube system. If you try to install your custom plugin it will give an error for duplicate xml plugin found.